# TypeError: <neo4j.work.result.Result object at 0x7f3f4bd01470> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, neo4j, rasa, neo4j-driver

For the below code, I am getting an error,please tell me how to resolve this

```
class GenerateQuery:

    @staticmethod
    def get_nlg(graph_query):
#        graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474",auth=("neo4j", "pass"))
#        graph_response = graph.evaluate(graph_query)
#        return graph_response
        driver = GraphDatabase.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j","pass"))
        with driver.session() as session:
            graph_response = session.run(graph_query)
            return graph_response

    @staticmethod
    def product_review(summary_comp,prod_comp):
        """
        :param summary_comp: product summary
        :param prod_comp: product node name
        :return: Summary/Review of the corresponding product
        """
        query = u'MATCH(s:Store)<-[r:REVIEWED]-(c:Customer) RETURN s.name as ProductName, r.summary as ProductReview'
        graph_response = GenerateQuery.get_nlg(query)
        return graph_response
```

when the result of the above is passed to the below code, it gives an error:

```
class ProductReview(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "action_review"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        intent = tracker.latest_message['intent']
        summary_comp = tracker.get_slot('summary')
        prod_comp = tracker.get_slot('node')
        graph_response = GenerateQuery.product_review(summary_comp,prod_comp)
        dispatcher.utter_message(json.dumps(graph_response))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sangeetha/Desktop/RiQue/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 939, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/sangeetha/Desktop/RiQue/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa_sdk/endpoint.py", line 112, in webhook
    return response.json(result, status=200)
  File "/home/sangeetha/Desktop/RiQue/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/response.py", line 210, in json
    dumps(body, **kwargs),
TypeError: <neo4j.work.result.Result object at 0x7f3f4bd01470> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: I assume you are using the official Python Bolt driver (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver), is that correct? 
What is the version of the Python driver you are using?

In any case, Result holds transaction-bound data and cannot be serialized.
You need to extract the data before the transaction closes and then the extracted data must be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

`Result` is not meant to be serialized, it holds transaction-bound data that are released upon transaction termination.

You must first extract the data before serializing it.
You can change `get_nlg` with something like:

```
return [record.data() for record in graph_response]
```

As a side note, `session.run` should preferably be replaced with `session.read_transaction` (a.k.a. [a transaction function](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/session-api/simple/#driver-async-transaction-fn)).